# Calculating an elevation for a gun to fire at for a certain range in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This may seem really simple to some, but I can't get my head around it.

If we have the following information for a gun firing:

Range  Elevation
100m -  50
200m -  76
300m -  110
400m -  140

How would we program to find the Elevation after a user has inputted a figure between 0-400 using Javascript?

Thanks for any answers in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or similar?

Comment: First you have to create a formula which calculates the elevation based on the range. That's pure math, after that you can convert it to Javascript.

Comment: Kinda looks like homework#

Comment: Heh, I dropped out of school 15 years ago man and now I'm paying for it. I wish it was.

Comment: I know how to do this on paper, that's easy just programming it is I'm clueless. If for example the user inputs 330m, we would get the difference between 110 and 140 multiply it by .3 and add it onto 110.

Comment: I'm confuised now. Is a distance of 115 supposed to be 50 elevation and a distance of 195 also a 50 elevation? Or are we trying to calculate some thing like: 115 = 52.34 and 195 = 74.8

Comment: So if the range the user enters was 115, the Elevation the gun would need to fire at would be 53.9. The difference between 50 and 76 is 26. We multiply 26 by .15 then add the answer(3.9) onto the lower number (50).

Comment: We're trying to find a Elevation on a set of numbers on a table from a user entry of a range. So if we're trying to find if we need to achieve 150 meters what elevation we require to shoot it at.

Comment: There's probably a quadractic function that can express this in one line, but it's kinda ahrd. DO you happen to ahve the zero point?

Comment: I appreciate all the work but Kaien hit the nail on the head with his way of doing it, exactly what I was hoping for. Thanks again Shilly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function cal() {

var constants = [50,76,110,140]; // An array of elevation heights at 100,200...

var input = document.getElementById('input').value;

if ( input == (constants.length * 100 )) {  // Exception case
  console.log(constants[constants.length-1]);
} else { 
for ( var i = 0; i < constants.length; i++ ) { 
  if ( String(input).charAt(0) == (i+1)) { // Check first digit of input
    console.log((input - ((i+1)*100))/100 * (constants[i+1]-constants[i]) + constants[i]); 
}}}}
```

```html
<input id="input" onchange="cal()">
```

Comment: This might actually be the correct solution if I interpreted the question wrong.

Comment: I thought of this but I didn't know how to code it, I was hoping there was some way of doing this using Arrays or something. 

With the ranges I'll be working with ill be writing thousands of if statements.

Thank you for your input though!

Comment: IS this what you need? Then I'll delete my faulty solution.

Comment: Kind of, I was really hoping for an array version somehow if its even possible.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks so much mate!

Answer (score 0):

An example, requires a modern browser.

```js
const data = [
  [100, 50],
  [200, 76],
  [300, 110],
  [400, 140],
];

const lookup = {
  0: () => 0
};
let previousPair = [0, 0];
for (let pair of data) {
  const [range, elevation] = pair;
  const [pRange, pElevation] = previousPair;
  lookup[range] = value => {
    const percRange = (value - pRange) / (range - pRange);
    const extraElevation = (elevation - pElevation) * percRange;
    return pElevation + extraElevation;
  };
  previousPair = pair;
}

const submitHanler = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const range = new FormData(event.target).get('range');
  for (let key of Object.keys(lookup)) {
    if (range <= key) {
      return (document.getElementById('elevation').value = lookup[key](range));
    }
  }
};

document.getElementById('calculate').addEventListener('submit', submitHanler, false);
```

```css
#calculate>input {
  width: 5em;
}
```

```html
<form id="calculate">
  <label for="range">Range</label>
  <input name="range" type="number" min="0" max="400" placeholder="0 to 400" required />
  <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
<input id="elevation" readonly />
```

Comment: Wow, what a completely different way of doing it! Thanks so much for your time and input!